# How do I find the IP address of my Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, headless, kali

I don't have a HDMI screen, nor do I have access to the router.

From what Ive been told, it has Kali installed.
I am connecting the Raspb directly to the computer with a Ethernet cable.

I have tried using advanced IP scanner without getting any results.

How do I find the IP of this thing so I can SSH into it?

Comment: I am assuming the network card on your computer can detect that its a direct connection and perform the cross over automatically? Other wise you need a cross over cable.   Also what type of OS for the computer?  you could try ssh pi@raspberrypi.local but not sure if your situation works with that.

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/90866/8697 Of course, if it is directly connected the computer will have a networking tool which will tell you.

Comment: `it has Kali installed` ... what is `it`?

Comment: @Chad G: 
Ive tried the pi@raspberrypi.local but no connection was opened., I am running windows 10.  Ive tried finding out if my card allows direct connection or not, but I am unable to find any info about it, I have a "Killer E2400" card.

Comment: @ChadG Please note that a cross over cable is never an issue for "decades" because nearly all devices can detect it, also a Raspberry Pi. Mention it may only confuse newbies.

Comment: @Ingo Thanks for making me feel old..../s

Comment: @ChadG Sorry, I wounldn't be impolite :) It is this medium ...

Comment: Are you sure that the Raspberry Pi 3B+ has an IP address?  Since you are direct connecting to a laptop, one approach is to run Wireshark on the lap top and view all traffic.  Power on the Pi and you should see either a DHCP request (the IP will be in the DHCP response) or an ARP announce message coming from the Pi that contains the IP address the Pi is using.

Answer (score 3):

Since all RPi use `b8:27:eb` as the first three octets of their MAC address, you can use `arp` from your Mac/Linux PC, but you'll need to refresh the arp cache first. Here's a `bash` script that will do the job. You can get more details from [my github page on the subject](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FindMyPi.md).

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

: ${1?"Usage: $0 ip subnet to scan. eg '192.168.1.'"}

subnet=$1
for addr in `seq 0 1 255 `; do
( ping -c 3 -t 5 $subnet$addr > /dev/null ) &
done
arp -a | grep b8:27:eb
```

Save this as a file on your Mac/Linux (or any machine that runs `bash`), make it executable, and then run it from your command line.

### EDIT dtd 20200104:

As ["The Foundation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation) has changed its organizational structure, a new OUI will be used on Raspberry Pi 4B models. Therefore, the original answer (above) must be updated to cover the latest model RPi. This change affects the last line of the `bash` script above. Make the following change:

**FROM:**

```
arp -a | grep b8:27:eb
```

**TO:**

```
arp -a |grep -E --ignore-case 'b8:27:eb|dc:a6:32'
```

**EXPLANATION:**
Prior to the release of Raspberry Pi 4B, all RPi's used the [OUI](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt) **`b8:27:eb`** as the first 3 *octets* of its [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). Beginning with Raspberry Pi 4B, a different organization is responsible for production, and the new OUI is: **`dc:a6:32`**. If the OUI of the MAC address of a device on the network matches one of these values, this tells us that one of the Raspberry Pi organizations have most likely made the hardware, and so it is most likely a Raspberry Pi device; the other possibility is that a device on the network is [MAC spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few different tools like nmap and other mapping tools.

But i would reccomend to use [angry ip scanner](https://angryip.org/download/) as it's  very simple to use.

Comment: Please read the question again. The asker has used a network scanner.